# How do I keep Django running on on my web server?

Tags: python, django, apache, shell

I am using dreamhost, and just finished a (as far as I can tell) successful installation of DJango on my VPS using Passenger.

Everything was installed from the shell via SSH - and I even launched the server using the command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888`

There are 2 issues I am having with this:

**Issue 1 (minor)**
I have to access my domain at *example.com:8888* - though I assume this could be fixed with some URL rewriting - yeah?

**Issue 2 (relatively major)**
As soon as I kill the terminal (ending my session) my site becomes inaccessible - how do I keep that from happening?

Comment: I think this is a better asked on server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamhost [doesn't allow long running processes](http://blog.dreamhosters.com/kbase/index.cgi?area=2449), they are killed off quite aggressively, you will have to run it on a per connection basis using [Passenger WSGI](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django).

Answer (score 2):

`runserver` is intended for development, not production. For running production Django applications on Dreamhost, see [the Django page on their wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django).